# Firebase - getting the latest document

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a node server running where I want to listen to a collection update and get the added data.
My solution was using ***db.collection("posts").onSnapshot*** to listen to a update and to get the latest I would order by date.

```
db.collection("posts").onSnapshot(async () => {
  const newPost = await db
    .collection("posts")
    .orderBy("date", "desc")
    .limit(1)
    .get()
    .data();
  console.log(newPost);
});
```

but ***.data()*** is not a function so I don't know how to retrive the data. I did a little debbuging and couldn't find any keys in the object that would give me the data from the post.

This is what it returns without .data()

```
    QuerySnapshot$1 {
  _delegate:
   QuerySnapshot {
     _firestore:
      FirebaseFirestore$1 {
        _persistenceKey: '[DEFAULT]',
        _settings: [FirestoreSettings],
        _settingsFrozen: true,
        _app: [FirebaseAppImpl],
        _databaseId: [DatabaseId],
        _credentials: [FirebaseCredentialsProvider],
        _queue: [AsyncQueue],
        _firestoreClient: [FirestoreClient] },
     _userDataWriter: UserDataWriter { firestore: [Firestore] },
     _snapshot:
      ViewSnapshot {
        query: [QueryImpl],
        docs: [DocumentSet],
        oldDocs: [DocumentSet],
        docChanges: [Array],
        mutatedKeys: [SortedSet],
        fromCache: false,
        syncStateChanged: true,
        excludesMetadataChanges: false },
     metadata:
      SnapshotMetadata { hasPendingWrites: false, fromCache: false },
     query:
      Query {
        _converter: null,
        _query: [QueryImpl],
        type: 'query',
        firestore: [FirebaseFirestore$1] } },
  _firestore:
   Firestore {
     _delegate:
      FirebaseFirestore$1 {
        _persistenceKey: '[DEFAULT]',
        _settings: [FirestoreSettings],
        _settingsFrozen: true,
        _app: [FirebaseAppImpl],
        _databaseId: [DatabaseId],
        _credentials: [FirebaseCredentialsProvider],
        _queue: [AsyncQueue],
        _firestoreClient: [FirestoreClient] },
     _persistenceProvider: IndexedDbPersistenceProvider {},
     INTERNAL: { delete: [Function: delete] },
     _appCompat:
      FirebaseAppImpl {
        firebase_: [Object],
        isDeleted_: false,
        name_: '[DEFAULT]',
        automaticDataCollectionEnabled_: false,
        options_: [Object],
        container: [ComponentContainer] } } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will have to first await the result of the `get()`, then reach into the returned [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) to find the document data.  Note that a QuerySnapshot contains zero or more documents, and you will need to use its API to find out if there are any documents returned.  Even if you think it will just return 1 document, you still need to reach into the result set to find that one document.

```
  const newPost = await db
    .collection("posts")
    .orderBy("date", "desc")
    .limit(1)
    .get();
  // newPost is a QuerySnapshot
  if (newPost.size > 0) {
    const data = newPost.docs[0].data();
    // do what you want with the document data
  }
  else {
    // figure out what you want to do if no documents were queried
  }
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly, I thought I checked .docs but apparently didn't.